# Using react-router in a non SPA

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

We have a NON SPA written in PHP using Laravel where we've been using React only in few pages.

I'm facing the following scenario: I have to create 2 views:

```
/admin/Locations
/admin/UserGroups
```

If the user types in the browser URL **http://localhost/admin/locations**, the server will redirect to the /admin/locations page, however, I want to render only `<Locations/>` component.

In other hand, if the user tries to access **http://localhost/admin/userGroups**, the server will redirect to /admin/userGroups page and react need to render only the `<UserGroups/>` component.

To build this app, I created a file called EngagementTrackerApp.js (that is the name of the module). Within the EngagementTrackerApp.js I have the following code:

```
render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/admin/locations" component={Locations} history={browserHistory} />   
        <Route path="/admin/userGroups" component={UserGroups} history={browserHistory}/>   
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('view')
);
```

In each page (Locations.blade.php and UserGroups.blade.php) I have a **div** called `<div id="view"></div>`.

It isn't working on this way, but, to get it working, I need to remove one of the routes.

For example. If I remove the route **locations**, the user can access the **UserGroup** view by the URL **http://localhost/admin/userGroups**:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/admin/et/userGroups" component={UserGroups} history={browserHistory}/>   
</BrowserRouter>
```

However, if I put both routes together it stops to work:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/admin/et/locations" component={Locations} history={browserHistory} />   
    <Route path="/admin/et/userGroups" component={UserGroups} history={browserHistory}/>   
</BrowserRouter>
```

And my **div** **view** is always blank.

What should I do, or, why is it working only for one route?

Comment: Try to remove the history prop , also if you are vising `http://localhost/admin/userGroup:` , your route should be `path="/admin/userGroups"` and not `path="/admin/et/userGroups"`

Comment: That was just a typo. I'm going to fix that in the question.

Comment: I tried. No success

Comment: check the answer

Comment: No... something that I see is that, inside the div, when I have just one router, and I'm in a opposite URL (e.g. accessing UserGroups by URL, however, I'm just the route for Locations, it shows inside the div that the React object is empty, and putting those routes together, it renders only the div without any content (React comment) inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify multiple routes within a `BrowserRouter`. You have to wrap them within a div

```
render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        <Route path="/admin/locations" component={Locations} history={browserHistory} />   
        <Route path="/admin/userGroups" component={UserGroups} history={browserHistory}/> 
        </div>  
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('view')
);
```

Comment: Is this rule written in somewhere?

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter, says `children: node
A single child element to render.`